# Understanding the code for finding the permutation of numbers x and y,(less than n) such that x*y is a perfect square and y -x is maximum (x < y)

Tags: algorithm

I read this function in a programming blog to do the aforementioned task,but I'm unable to understand it . (Also x*y should be maximum).Also the preference for maximizing x*y is more than y-x .

```
       long long ans = 0;
        int X,Y;

    for( i = 2;i <= n / i;++i){
        int k = n / (i * i);
        int y = k *i*i;
        int x = k * (i - 1) * (i - 1);

        if((long long)x * y > ans){
            ans = (long long)x * y;
            X = x;
            Y = y;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't do anything. It repeatedly assigns some values to local variables, and does nothing with these values.

Comment: sorry my bad,have made the changes

Comment: Your question title doesn't make sense.  Literally, there are only 2 permutations of `x` and `y`: `[x, y]` and `[y, x]`, and the rest makes no sense.  Perhaps you just want to "find x and y such that ..."

Comment: That code doesn't do what the question describes; it maximises x*y not y-x. If you wanted to maximise y-x, just let y=(n-1)^2, and x=1.

Comment: The code is incorrect.  The line `int x = k * (i-1) * (i-1);` should be replaced with `int x = k;`

Comment: @bazzargh: Please see that in the question description OP says 'x*y should be maximum'.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff If he Replaces it with `int x = k`, `x * y` will not be a perfect square.

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow,so there might be a chance of framing the question in the wrong way,pardon me for that

Comment: @p5coder y-x and x*y will not be maximised at the same time. So the question would still have to be reworded for this to make sense.

Comment: @bazzargh made the change

Comment: @P5Coder - Can you calculate `x*y` for my case? )))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `i <= n / i` ensures that the values `x` and `y` are less than `n`, as those are derived from the square of `i`, inside the loop.
   *(`k` is derived from `n` and `i`. And `x` and `y` are in turn derived from `k` and `i`.)*
2. `int k = n / (i * i);`, `int y = k * i * i;`, `int x = k * (i - 1) * (i - 1);` ensures that the value `x * y` is a perfect square.
   *(since `x * y` = `k * k * i * i * (i - 1) * (i - 1)`. i.e `x * y` is a perfect square of `k * i * (i - 1)`).*
   Also, `x` is less than `y` because `x` derives from `(i - 1)` whereas `y` from `i`.
3. The three statements in the `if` loop at the end just keep a track of the pair having largest `x * y`.

Comment: And why would these specific values for `x` and `y` be chosen? The code as posted doesn't make sense, and doesn't do what the title says.

Comment: thanks ,it was quite helpful, but how is it ensured that y-x is maximum ?

Comment: The code the OP had posted the first time did not make sense but this one does. `x` and `y` are chosen on the basis that they are smaller than n, their product is a perfect square, `x` < `y`, `y - x` is maximum and `x * y` is maximum.

Comment: @P5Coder How is it ensured that y - x is maximum ?

Comment: As the value of `i` is increasing, obviously the difference between `k * i * i` and `k * (i - 1) * (i - 1)` will increase.

Comment: oh,sorry ,it was obvious,didn't notice it ,thanks a lot for the reply